# Picasso does not load in android studio

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

i receive NPE when i want to show pics in picasso,
pay attention that i've another adapter which i used picasso,
but in my new adapter this npe error for boolean happens,
and my friends used this code and it performed well,
here is the code that error says

```
public boolean isVideoNews() {
    return !image.isEmpty() && !video.isEmpty() ;
}
```

and the part that is related to this code in my adapter

```
videoIndicator.setVisibility(news.isVideoNews() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

my adapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
private List<News> newsList;

public NewsAdapter(List<News> newsList) {
    this.newsList = newsList;
}

@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new NewsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_news, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindNews(newsList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsList.size();
}


class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView newsImageView;
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private TextView dateTextView;
    private View videoIndicator;

    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        newsImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_image);
        videoIndicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_VideoIndicator);
        titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_title);
        dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_date);
    }

    public void bindNews(News news) {
        Picasso.get().load(news.getImage()).into(newsImageView);
        videoIndicator.setVisibility(news.isVideoNews() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        titleTextView.setText(news.getTitle());
        dateTextView.setText(news.getDate());
    }
}
}
```

and this is my data model

```
public class News {
private int id;
private String title;
private String content;
private String date;
private String image;
private String video;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getVideo() {
    return video;
}

public void setVideo(String video) {
    this.video = video;
}

public boolean isVideoNews() {
    return !image.isEmpty() && !video.isEmpty() ;
}
}
```

Error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.melal.newsapp, PID: 5958
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.home.NewsAdapter$NewsViewHolder.bindNews(NewsAdapter.java:53)
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.home.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:31)
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.home.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:17)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.melal.newsapp, PID: 9523
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.data.News.isVideoNews(News.java:60)
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.home.NewsAdapter$NewsViewHolder.bindNews(NewsAdapter.java:53)
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.home.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:30)
    at com.example.melal.newsapp.home.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:16)
```

I get every data when I debug and my texts and title and every things show on UI but just my image does not show,my banners pic show in my another adapter on UI but main problem is the adapter that i told,

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to check here null and empty values for path of Image.

Put following line in if condition like:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(news.getImage())) {
   // Load default image
   newsImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
} else {
    Picasso.get().load(news.getImage()).into(newsImageView);
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide seralized name and expose that field of Model class so that your gson can parse it. Currently you have not set it to any field and thus GSON is not parsing your response accordingly. Below is sample code for how to define it in class. You need to expose all your class fields accordingly.

```
@SerializedName("foo")      //name inside quotes must match with your json field name.
@Expose
private String foo;
```